# Lifetime vs mean time between failure (MTBF)

Tags: cox-model, reliability

I'm wondering about the difference between [MTBF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_time_between_failures) and [lifetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay#Mean_lifetime) (I've to admit I'm not sure whether the last link is too specific..).

[image: survival]
[source](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/survival-analysis-basics)

[image: mtbf]
[source](https://www.shsu.edu/%7Emgt_ves/mgt481/lesson12/sld015.htm)

To make it precise: Let's say there is a single mechanical item, what would MTBF and lifetime tell about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the definition of "lifetime" and the underlying probability distribution.

For the [exponential decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) you show in the second display, if the survival function is $S(t)=\exp (-\lambda t)$, then the *mean* survival (MTBF, mean time between failures, for independent events) is at $t_{\text{mean}} = 1/\lambda$. That's one potential definition of "lifetime."

In the first display, however, you use *median* survival as the definition of "lifetime": the time at which half of individuals have experienced the event (survival probability of 0.5). For an exponential survival model, that median survival time is at $t_{1/2}=\ln 2/\lambda$. That's a different, shorter time for this distribution.

Even in this simple situation with an exponential survival model, which definition of "lifetime" do you want to use?

Things become more complicated with other underlying survival distributions or in non-parametric models of censored survival times, like a Cox model. If the last observation time is a censoring time rather than an event time, you can't calculate a "mean" survival time in the usual way with a non-parametric model; you are forced to use something like a "restricted mean survival time" only considering times up to some specified maximum value. That's one reason why median survival is often used as the "lifetime" measure.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear input and boiling it down! Is there a metric one could use "every" time to compare between different items, objects, individuals,.. ? Or more precise: Is there something wrong using the MTBF to compare the reliability of a component from different companies?

Comment: @Ben there's nothing wrong with MTBF if it's calculated correctly. MTBF seems to be used a lot for physical devices like hard drives, with failure times tending to have an exponential or Weibull distribution. In clinical survival studies, however, the underlying survival-time distributions aren't always so clear and calculating mean survival isn't always so simple; median survival is more typical then.

Comment: Thanks again! As much as I read the MTBF considers only the flat region from this bathtub-curve (explicitly ignoring early failures and worn out devices). From my pov this is too much to assume on a daily basis, especially when I don't know anything about the type of a failure. Hence, it feels, at least for me, as if a median survival is (much) more general, or?

Comment: @Ben that's what I mean by "calculated correctly." Always read the details of methods. A correct MTBF could, say, help to estimate the cost per year of replacing failed devices in a way that the median wouldn't. I mostly deal with clinical survival data, for which median survival seems to be the default.

Comment: Understand, jfyi: When buying technical items, the MTBF is "just" a number in a datasheet where one knows nothing about how this value was calculated. One can already be quite happy when "regular" parameters are correct, like precision and so on.